# What does The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given. mean and why do I only get it on the remote?

Tags: laravel

I'm running an app on PagodaBox. Locally it works fine, but when I push it to pagoda, I get the following error:

The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given.

Here is the route:

```
Route::get('tweets/{q}', function($q)
{
    return Twitter::getSearch(array('q' => $q, 'count' => 5, 'lang' => 'sv', 'result_type' => 'recent'));
});
```

Other routes work fine. What does this error mean and what could cause this error?

Comment: It looks like Twitter::getSearch is returning an object instead of a string. Route::get expects a string to be returned, since Twitter::getSearch is returning an object instead of string, thus the error. You may need to post what is inside Twitter::getSearch to let you know what could be the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**create the following function**

```
function utf8_encode_deep(&$input) {
    if (is_string($input)) {
        $input = utf8_encode($input);
    } else if (is_array($input)) {
        foreach ($input as &$value) {
            self::utf8_encode_deep($value);
        }

        unset($value);
    } else if (is_object($input)) {
        $vars = array_keys(get_object_vars($input));

        foreach ($vars as $var) {
            utf8_encode_deep($input->$var);
        }
    }
```

**try to do the following**

```
$response = Twitter::getSearch(array('q' => $q, 'count' => 5, 'lang' => 'sv', 'result_type' => 'recent'));

utf8_encode_deep($response);

return response;
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this to see what is returned.

```
dd(Twitter::getSearch(array('q' => $q, 'count' => 5, 'lang' => 'sv', 'result_type' => 'recent')));
```

You have to return View class which has __toString() method or if it's ajax request then something like Response::json($data);